# Meaning of "doodle let me go" and "yaller girls"

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

I've recently watched the movie "The Lighthouse" directed by Robert Eggers and in one of the scenes in the movie two main characters were singing a song containing following lyrics:

> "Doodle let me go, me girls, doodle let me go,
>   Hurrah, me yaller girls, doodle let me go!"

Similar lyrics can be found in this song [A. L. Lloyd - Doodle Let Me Go](https://genius.com/A-l-lloyd-doodle-let-me-go-yaller-girls-lyrics).
Could you help me to understand what "doodle let me go" and "yaller girls" phrases mean?

Comment: Dunno about ***doodle*** (dialectal / affected form of imperative ***do** [please]*?). But [***Yellow Gals** (Girls) are not girls dressed in yellow or with blond hair and not even oriental ones, they are rather mulatto girls (creole) of the West Indies, according to the nineteenth-century seafaring jargon*](https://terreceltiche.altervista.org/yellow-gals-girls-or-irish-girl/) (apparently associated with "chorus girls" as well as plantation slaves). But this is seriously antiquated slang, that would be totally unknown to almost all native speakers today. History, not language.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you very much for helping with "yaller girls" phrase. I also found that [the meaning of the term doodle is still open to multiple explanations](https://terreceltiche.altervista.org/doodle-let-go-yaller-girls/) and that one of the explanation of "doodle" is indeed "affected form of imperative do [please]".

Comment: Yurii, in songwriting, particularly of the jocular type, nonsense lyrics are common. They don't always have to mean anything.

Comment: Agreeing in part with @MichaelHarvey, they probably don’t mean anything to the singer(s) but would have meant something to the folk authors of the song at some point in the past. For this reason the precise meaning isn’t important in these sort of traditional songs. For example, some Americans may not understand the precise derivation and meaning of all the words in the song “Yankee Doodle” but they nevertheless enjoy singing it. In Australia, our national song is “Waltzing Matilda” and yet many of the words in it are quaintly archaic and hardly understood by most Australians.

Answer (score 1):

Quite obviously this song is a sailor's song about a visit to a cat-house.  Sorry to be so frank, but that's what it is.  Yaller girls are mixed-race females who work and live there.  Doodle let me go could be sailor slang for making a request of the onboard officer to allow onshore leave.  Or it could be a sailor's playful way of asking his equipment to co-operate so he can fully enjoy the visit.  Not a very uplifting song, but it's a slice of real life experienced by real people for centuries.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion "doodle let me go" should be interpreted as "do, do let me go."